# Image map support in firefox, chrome and other browsers

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, standards

Are image maps supported in chrome and firefox? [w3schools seems to suggest they are](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp).

Given this, why would the following HTML fail? (Image is displayed but no links work - It does work correctly in IE)

```
<img src="Images/backgroundFinal.png" usemap="#mainImageMap" alt="MainBackground" style="border: none;" />
            <map id="mainImageMap">
                <area shape="rect" alt="Home Page" title="Home Page" coords="309,198,413,223" href="Default.aspx" target="" />
                <area shape="rect" alt="About me" title="About me" coords="245,334,319,353" href="About.aspx" target="" />
                <area shape="rect" alt="Gallery" title="Gallery" coords="437,271,497,300" href="Gallery.aspx" target="" />
                <area shape="rect" alt="Tattoo" title="Tattoo" coords="249,478,307,503" href="Tattoo.aspx" target="" />
                <area shape="rect" alt="Contacts" title="Contacts" coords="395,521,464,544" href="Contact.aspx" target="" />
            </map>
```

Comment: Image maps are definitely supported. What are the dimensions of the image?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try changing `<map id="mainImageMap">` to `<map name="mainImageMap">`. You can keep the `id` if required but just make sure a `name`attribute` is there.