# Place div elements on responsive background with defined "workspace" area (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am relatively new to responsive design.  My client provided an image to use for the background of a web app.  It has some flare and a rectangular area that is used for the "workspace" of the web app.  I have made this background image responsive.  What I want to do is make a workspace div that will scale with the background image and maintain position over the provided workspace area on the image.  Please see the following question for a good visual example of this functionality.

[Place div elements on responsive background (Bootstrap 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714126/place-div-elements-on-responsive-background-bootstrap-3)

My background image is similar to the envelope in the example above but is not diagonally positioned.  So that removes a bit of complexity.  I have tried with 12 columns and couldn't get the overlayPane to position properly.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

**CSS:**

```
    html, body
    {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .bg_img
    {
        background: url('../Images/BACKGROUND.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv" class="bg_img" style="height: 100%;">
        <div id="overlayPane">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Bummer that there is no solution to this. What you want is to pin a div to the resizing action of the background-size cover, which, if anything is a whole lot of math for jQuery since the contents don't size down and up in a similar "stretchy" fashion -- except for fitText.js. The only way to fake this is to make a few background images for major breakpoints and landscapes, make it a fixed background, and an absolute positioned div and set up the media queries

Comment: Though, you may be able to do a foreground image and use http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html -- you'd have to capture the coordinates. I have no clue how to do it

Comment: It would save you a lot of headaches if you could get your client to supply the background with the flare and the rectangular area separately as two images...

Comment: @BootstrapThemer I researched your image map suggestion. By dissecting the link you provided and using an online image map maker tool, I was able to produce a solution that worked. It was a little dirty and could use some clean up. However, there seems to be an issue with image maps / areas and Firefox/Chrome. It didn't function at all in those browsers. Ultimately, I went with your first suggestion to make different sized background images with media queries. So the answer to the question is provided by your image map suggestion. I just chose to go another way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527290/image-map-support-in-firefox-chrome-and-other-browsers -- add a name to the map.